How to bypass "No passkeys available" Chrome dialog using Puppeteer?

I have trouble getting pass the Chrome native dialog of "No passkeys available" during the login process using Puppeteer. This seems like something recently added (April 2024).
So far, I've tried using all the following:

import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra";
import AnonymizeUAPlugin from "puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua";
import StealthPlugin from "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth";
import AdblockerPlugin from "puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker";
import UserPreferencePlugin from "puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences";

const stealth = StealthPlugin();
stealth.enabledEvasions.delete("iframe.contentWindow");
stealth.enabledEvasions.delete("media.codecs");
puppeteer.use(stealth);
puppeteer.use(AnonymizeUAPlugin());
puppeteer.use(AdblockerPlugin({ blockTrackers: true }));
puppeteer.use(
  UserPreferencePlugin({
    userPrefs: {
      safebrowsing: {
        enabled: false,
        enhanced: false,
      },
    },
  })
);


As well as adding these args:
 args: [
      "--autoplay-policy=user-gesture-required",
      "--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows",
      "--disable-breakpad",
      "--disable-client-side-phishing-detection",
      "--disable-component-update",
      "--disable-default-apps",
      "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
      "--disable-domain-reliability",
      "--disable-extensions",
    ]

Hopefully this can address as I'm trying to automate my chrome for testing purposes

you'll probably need to turn off passkeys in your google account there.

Thanks that worked. but just wondering in general, does puppeteer allow for interaction with native pop-ups like this within chrome?

it's generally limited to the DOM.  There are "robot" type frameworks you can use for other things...ex: "autoit": https://pypi.org/project/autoit/
